# Linear algebra, eigenspace property

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $\vec{v}$ be an eigenvector of $A$ with corresponding eigenvalue $\lambda$ and $c$ a scalar. show that $v$ is an eigenvector of $A-cI$ with corresponding eigenvalue $\lambda-c$.

I'm not sure if the question is asking for a specific example to demonstrate this, or if it is asking in a general sense. Naturally this problem is quite simple by example, but I'm not sure how to begin a general proof.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that $$(A-cI)v=Av-cIv=\lambda v-cv=(\lambda-c)v$$
Hence $v$ is an eigenvector of $A-cI$ with eigenvalue $\lambda-c$.

Answer (score 1):

I would just say:

since $Av=\lambda v$ then we have

$(A-cI)v=Av-cIv=\lambda v -cv=(\lambda -c)v$ which shows that $v$ is still an eigenvector with eigenvalue $\lambda -c$.